# QUARTUS II: Error: Port "cg" does not exist in macro function "ADD0"

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus-ii, error

So i got 8 error while compiling this 4 bit Carry-lookahead adder. I got the above error for ports cg and cp in macro functions ADD0-ADD3. For my code check the attachments. Edit: Here i've copied the code in:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity cla4 is -- 4-bit CLA structural model: top entity
port( 
    a, b                  : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    carryin               : in std_logic;
    sum, ch, cq           : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    cgout, cpout, overflow: out std_logic);
end cla4;

architecture arch of cla4 is
    component fagp -- component declaration
    port( 
        a, b, cin   : in std_logic;
        sum, cg, cp : out std_logic);
    end component;

    component cla_logic -- component declaration CLA-generator
    port( 
        g, p          : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        cin           : in std_logic;
        c             : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        cgout, cpout  : out std_logic);
    end component;

    signal carry  : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); --local signals
    signal cg, cp : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal cout   : std_logic;

begin
        carry(0) <= carryin;

        ADD0: fagp
        port map (a(0), b(0), carry(0), sum(0), cg(0), cp(0));

        ADD1: fagp
        port map (a(1), b(1), carry(1), sum(1), cg(1), cp(1));

        ADD2: fagp
        port map (a(2), b(2), carry(2), sum(2), cg(2), cp(2));

        ADD3: fagp
        port map (a(3), b(3), carry(3), sum(3), cg(3), cp(3));

        --generate carries from
        --propagate and generate values
        --from full_adder_g_p_g_p
        CLA: cla_logic
        port map(cg, cp, carryin, carry(3 downto 1), cout, cpout);

        cgout <= cout;
        overflow <= carry(3) xor cout;
end arch;
```

cla_logic:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity cla_logic is
port(
    G, P         : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    CIN          : in std_logic;
    C            : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); -- “internal” carry
    CGOUT, CPOUT : out std_logic);
end cla_logic;

architecture arch of cla_logic is
begin
    C(0) <= G(0) or (P(0) and CIN);
    C(1) <= G(1) or (G(0) and P(1)) or (CIN and P(0) and P(1)); 
    C(2) <= G(2) or (G(1) and P(2)) or (G(0) and P(1) and P(2)) or (CIN and P(0) and P(1) and P(2));
    CGOUT<= G(3) or (G(2) and P(3)) or (G(0) and P(2) and P(3)) or (G(0) and P(1) and P(2) and P(3)) or (CIN and P(0) and P(1) and P(2) and P(3));
    CPOUT<= (P(3) and P(2) and P(1) and P(0));
end arch;
```

fagp:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity fagp is
port( 
    a, b, cin : in std_logic;
    sum, g, p : out std_logic);
end fagp;

architecture arch of fagp is
begin
    sum <= a xor b xor cin;
    p <= a and b; --complete this
    g <= a or b; --complete this
end arch;
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in `fagp` component declaration. In the `entity` you have follow port names `sum, g, p : out std_logic`, but when you declare the component in `cla4` you use other names `sum, cg, cp : out std_logic);`.

So you need just fix the mistake and your code will work.

```
component fagp -- component declaration
port( 
    a, b, cin   : in std_logic;
    sum, g, p : out std_logic);
end component;
```

Or you can use another method without component declaration (to avoid errors in names or etc.):

```
ADD0: entity work.fagp
port map (a(0), b(0), carry(0), sum(0), cg(0), cp(0));
```

Comment: A third alternative - rename port signals g and p to cg and cp respectively in entity fagp and it's architecture arch.